# How to read large Excel Files having 1 million to 5 million rows in React JS/ JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, excel, sheetjs

I need to read large Excel files having 1million to 5 million rows in React JS.
I want to convert all of the records into JSON objects.

Is there any library/npm package which is capable of handling large excel files?
Currently I am using sheet js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx
But this package is not working with large datasets.

What are the fastest ways to process large Excel file in JavaScript?

Below is my current code:

```
import './App.css';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

function App() {
  const readExcel = (e) =>{
    console.log("start time", new Date());
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

   
      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        const bufferArray = e.target.result;
        const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray,{type:'buffer'});
        const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
        const ws =  wb.Sheets[wsname];
        const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);
        resolve(data);
      }

      fileReader.onerror = (error) =>{
        console.log("error", error);
        reject(error);
      }
    })

    promise.then((data)=>{
      console.log("end time", new Date());
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type={'file'} onChange={readExcel} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Orher programs exist that handle large dara files (much) better than Excel.

Comment: @SolarMike, I need to read Excel files only using React JS/JavaScript, and convert data into JSON

Comment: you got any solution for this @code_hr ??